# kernel module write to proc

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have made the following kernel module to create a process "hello_proc" in /proc directory:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>

static int hello_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
    seq_printf(m, "P5 : Hello proc!\n");
    return 0;
}

static int hello_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
    return single_open(file, hello_proc_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations hello_proc_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = hello_proc_open,
    .read = seq_read,
    .write = seq_write,
    .llseek = seq_lseek,
    .release = single_release,
};

static int hello_proc_init(void) {
    proc_create("hello_proc", 0, NULL, &hello_proc_fops);
    printk("P5 : Process hello proc created");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_proc_exit(void) {
    remove_proc_entry("hello_proc", NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(hello_proc_init);
module_exit(hello_proc_exit);
```

I inserted the module and a proc file "hello_proc" was created successfully in directory /proc. The next thing I want to do is to write the output of command:

```
ls -l -t /proc | head -21 > /proc/hello_proc
```

to file "hello_proc" followed by reading as well. When I do (as root):

```
root@anubhav-Inspiron-3421:~$ ls -l -t /proc | head -21 > /proc/hello_proc
```

the execution just stops.

Now, I checked a lot of codes and resources on internet, but could not find one that explains how to write to a proc file. No resource on youtube either.

The best thing I found for writing to proc file were codes that were creating proc files using function "create_proc_entry", which looked fairly simple but for an older kernel version, different than mine. Any suggestions/directions to move ahead.

Answer (score 3):

`seq_write` doesn't do what you might think. It's actually like `seq_printf` except it just writes a fixed number of bytes (rather than formatted outpuut). The seq_xxx API doesn't support writing to the device. You have to implement that separately.

For a fairly simple model of how to create a writable device using single_open on the read side, take a look at `proc_pid_set_comm_operations`, which implements `/proc/<pid>/comm` and also supports writing.

Also, note that `create_proc_entry` was deprecated but it's pretty straight-forward to change `create_proc_entry` to `proc_create`. As described in Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt:

```
-       entry = create_proc_entry("sequence", 0, NULL);
-       if (entry)
-               entry->proc_fops = &ct_file_ops;
+       entry = proc_create("sequence", 0, NULL, &ct_file_ops);
```